# In AngularJS, how do I get two buttons to call different functions?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on something where you have a reset button, a button to save changes to a database object, and I added a delete button next to it. No matter what I do, I can't seem to find how to get the two different buttons to call different functions. I'm very new at this...

Here's the HTML part.

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabeled="myForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes / Create</button>
      <button type="remove" value="Remove" ng-model="deleteProduct()" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The ng-model part I added doesn't seem to do anything. No matter what I do, I can't get it to call a different function to the Save button. *

*Disclaimer I took over this project and didn't write it from scratch. I've tried crawling through the code and adding things everywhere (with console.log lines added in to see if they ever get called) but I can't seem to crack it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try to use ng-click for the buttons.

Comment: `ng-model` defines a property on the scope, so it is looking for a variable name returned by the scope function `deleteProduct()`

Comment: `type="remove"` is not valid html, you should have a look at the docs for `ng-click` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick something like `type="button" ng-click="deleteProduct"`

Comment: Yeah, already tried that. Same behaviour. I still see in the console "addProduct called" showing it's going to the same function. The deleteProduct function just has a console.log line in it at the minute but it never gets called.

Comment: Can't see any problems with that code: <button type="remove" value="Remove" ng-click="deleteProduct()" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>. Perhapse your Delete Product Form is out of your controllers scope?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-click` to assign a click listener in Angular.

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>

<button type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabeled="myForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Save Changes / Create</button>
```

In your controller find these functions to perform specific operations that you need.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  console.log("Submit button clicked");
}

$scope.cancel = function() {
  console.log("Cancell button clicked");
}
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the right answer, but I can't get it to work. I tried wrapping the addProduct function in $scope.submit and it told me $scope wasn't defined. This isn't in controllers, it's in routes. When I go to controllers, I find a $scope.submit function, but when I put a conole.log in there it never spits out so I don't know what to think. While wandering through this code I've found the same function seemingly written more than once, I suspect this was a "throw stuff at it and see if it works" job

Comment: Maybe it was because I had the $scope outside the function, but when I put it inside the function it still never gets called. Surprisingly adding the ng-click didn't seem to do anything, but neither did it break anything. I suspect it's being ignored

Answer (score 1):

Try ng-click for function call use like

```
<button ng-click="myFunc()">OK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Some corrections need to be made in your code :**

- It should be `ng-disabled` instead of `ng-disabeled`.
- `type="remove"` is not valid type of the element. Use `type="button"` with `ng-click="remove()"`

**Working code :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      console.log("cancel call");
    }
    
    $scope.save = function() {
      console.log("save call");    
    }
    
    $scope.remove = function() {
      console.log("remove call");    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form name="myForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save Changes / Create</button>
      <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="remove()" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```